# How much traffic can a app on a Heroku free tier handle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I want to know how many concurent number of users at a time can use app deploy on free tier of heroku?

Note : App server is by default

Comment: http://discuss.bootstrapped.fm/t/will-i-end-up-in-trouble-with-my-landing-page-on-heroku-free-dyno/529/11

Comment: At the link above you will find an example running 70,000 unique requests per day. At least you now have a ballpark figure to work with of what is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no definitive answer to that. It depends of too many factors: what requests your users are making. How heavy/optimized those requests are being the two biggest ones.

A [free dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types#available-dyno-types) will  get 512MB of RAM, and 1CPU share from the instance machine.
You'll need to do benchmarking to know what kind of traffic your app can handle with that, as it does depend of your app's code.

Comment: @haseeb This depends on what your requests do. If they are fast, you can do many of them, if the are slow, not so much. The only definitive answer you'll get is: set it up and perform a benchmark using your expected traffic patterns.